# after press keybutton and set input's value = '' , the value in FormGroup doesn't reset, Angular

Tags: angular, forms, input, keyboard

I have many pages with their own different FormGroup.
Some FormGroup elements have a default value, like '0'.
In the main parent component, I wrote @HostListener for the key button 'Esc'.
When a user presses the key button 'Esc' AND input has a focus, and some value, I set input value '' or null.
But after submitting an element of the FormGroup has still the default value.
How does fix this, or maybe use another logic?

Comment: Can you provide some code on stackblitz.com to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code it's just a hunch of what is happening. But the way you described your problem, it leads me to think that even if your function on `esc` key sets input value to ´null´ that doesn't necessarily mean `FormGroup` value is updated to `null`. Either A) also check if `FormGorup` value is updated when using the `esc` key or B) when submitting your form, update formGroup to reflect your desired input values.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `Name : <input type="text" [formControl]="nameFormcontrol" /> {{nameFormcontrol.value}} <br /><br />
  Age : <input type="text" [formControl]="ageFormcontrol" /> {{ageFormcontrol.value}}`,
  styles: [``],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(
    event: KeyboardEvent
  ) {
    console.log('escape was pressed', event);
    this.form.get('name').setValue(null);
    this.form.get('age').setValue(null);
}

  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  nameFormcontrol;
  ageFormcontrol;

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nameFormcontrol = this.form.get('name');
    this.ageFormcontrol = this.form.get('age');

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe( () => {
      this.cdr.detectChanges()
    })
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log(changes)
  }
}
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-form-group-value-change-uzoqjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput.component.ts

Comment: Thank you. I found a good idea for me in your answer, but I made mistake, and don't correctly describe: "I have many pages, with routing, so I can't binding form with @Input()